# In $\triangle ABC$, angles $B$ and $C$ satisfy $2\tan x - k ( 1 + \tan 2 x)=0$; what is $A$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

> In a $\triangle ABC$, $\angle B <  \angle C$ and values of $B$ and $C$ satisfy equation $2 \tan x – k (1 + \tan ^2x) = 0$ where $(0 \lt k \lt 1)$ . Then measure of angle $A$ is?

Note that $\tan B$ and $\tan C$ are its roots , So 
$$\text{sum of roots} = \dfrac2k$$
and
$$\text{product of roots} = 1\,.$$ 
Then , 
$$\tan ( B + C) = \tan ( \pi - A)\,$$
Expanding $\tan( B + C)$, we found it not defined.  The tangent is not defined at when the argument is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. 
So, $$\tan (\pi - A) = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\text{ and }\angle A=\frac{\pi}{2} $$

Comment: Did you mean $\tan^2(x)$, rather than $\tan(2x)$?  The equation as it is can be rewritten as a cubic in $\tan(x)$, and can result in three possible triangles.  For example, $k=\frac{3}{7}$ produces three distinct possible $\big(\angle A,\angle B,\angle C\big)$, as $\tan(x)$ can be anything from $\frac{-1-\sqrt{22}}{7}$, $\frac{1}{2}$, and $\frac{-1+\sqrt{22}}{7}$.

Comment: On the other hand, if the equation is $2\,\tan(x)-k\,\big(1+\tan^2(x)\big)=0$, then $\angle B+\angle C=\frac{\pi}{2}$, so that $\angle A=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: No, post the solution in your question.  You should have written your attempt in your question from the beginning.  Questions that show attempts by the askers tend to be positively received.